# What are the consequences to failing a heist?

Tags: the-swindle

I just failed a heist, and as far as I can tell the only thing I lost was the money I found on that heist. All the cash I collected from previous heists still seems to be in the bank, despite the fact I never returned to the airship. The one skill I unlocked, Hacking Level 1, is still unlocked as well. The only consequence I've noticed is that my Thief died, but he was freely replaced with a new one.

What's the consequence for failing a heist?

Comment: I think the main consequence is just the time lost before the big "Final heist," which is 100 days after you start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing for a while last night, I can confirm that lost time is the main  penalty for a failed heist.

One additional thing worth noting is that there is at least one ability that is dependent on the amount of experience your current thief has. It allows you to earn more money based on the number of successful heists for your currently active thief.

The "Successful Heists" counter resets with each new thief, so, the more success a character has, the more money they stand to make once that ability is unlocked.